Under what circumstances Is a symmetric matrix representable as a Coulomb matrix?
Question:
I am exploring a neural network architecture inspired by physical interactions, where each neuron has associated "mass" and "position" vectors. The weight matrix between neurons is computed using a force-like inverse-square law interaction, reminiscent of the Coulomb interaction between charged particles. For two neurons with "mass" vectors $\mu_i$ and $\mu_j$ located at positions $x_i$ and $x_j$, the weight $w_{ij}$ is defined as:
$$
w_{ij} = \frac{\mu_i \cdot \mu_j}{\|x_i - x_j\|^2}
$$
This formulation is structurally similar to the Coulomb matrix used in quantum chemistry to represent atomic interactions in molecules, where the entries are defined as:
$$
C_{ij} = 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{Z_i Z_j}{\|x_i - x_j\|} & \text{if } i \neq j \\
0.5 Z_i^{2.4} & \text{if } i = j
\end{cases}
$$
where $Z_i$ and $Z_j$ are atomic charges.
Given this context, I am interested in the following theoretical question:

Under what circumstances can a general symmetric matrix $W$ be represented in the form of a Coulomb-like matrix?

That is, when does there exist a set of vectors $\{ \mu_i, x_i \}$ such that:
$$
w_{ij} = \frac{\mu_i \cdot \mu_j}{\|x_i - x_j\|^2} \quad \forall i, j
$$
Motivation:
Exploring the possibility of representing a symmetric weight matrix $W$ as a Coulomb-like matrix could potentially confirm that neural networks using this "force-based" weight concept can learn any function representable by a traditional network using symmetric matrices. Since multilayer perceptrons with symmetric weight matrices are known to be universal function approximators, establishing a comparable representational capability in neural networks with force-based interactions could open new avenues for designing computationally efficient and scalable neural architectures.
The inquiry into whether any symmetric matrix can be represented as a Coulomb matrix underpins the theoretical validity of using such architectures in broader machine learning applications. Such a representation would not only underscore the universality of force-based neural networks but also provide a foundational argument for their use in scenarios where traditional neural architectures might be computationally prohibitive.
Any insights into conditions, dimensionality constraints, or special cases where such a representation is feasible would be greatly appreciated!
The idea to use vectors instead of real numbers for "mass" comes from physics:
Suppose that two bodies $1,2$ with each mass $m_i$ and electric charge $q_i$ have between them two forces: Coulomb's Force and Newton's Gravity force:
$$
F_C = \frac{q_1 \cdot q_2}{|x_1-x_2|^2}, F_N = \frac{m_1 \cdot m_2}{|x_1-x_2|^2}
$$
But by Newton's principle, the forces can be added, thus:
$$
F_{12} = F_C + F_N = \frac{(m_1 \cdot m_2 + q_1 \cdot q_2 )}{|x_1-x_2|^2}
$$
which can be written as:
$$
F_{12} = F_C + F_N = \frac{\langle \mu_1, \mu_2\rangle}{|x_1-x_2|^2}
$$
where $\mu_i = (m_i, q_i)$ is a two-dimensional vector with components mass and charge.
I am not imposing restrictions on the diagonal of the symmetric matrix. The dimensions of the mass and position vectors can be different.
Edit: While modifying the original idea, after experiments with custom neural networks, to the following and while keeping the intention the same, I am asking if every symmetric matrix with $0$ on the diagonal can be written as:
$$w_{ij} = \langle m_i, m_j \rangle |x_i-x_j|^2$$
This simplifies the analysis I hope since then we do not divide through $0$.
Second edit: A somehow cheating solution which solves the problem above would be to use the spectral theorem, whereby a real symmetric matrix $w_ij$ can be decomposed into:
$$ w_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n q_{ik} \lambda_k q_{jk}$$
where $q_i := (q_{i1},\cdots,q_{in})$ is an n-dim vector and $\lambda_k$ is a real number. The $\lambda_k$ and $q_k$ are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $W$. The $q_k$ are pairwise orthogonal. Using this knowledge that every symmetric matrix can be decomposed this way, we might want to impose on the weights of the neural network the 'restriction' that they are generated this way for $d$ being the dimension of the vectors $q_k$ which could in theory be large as $n$, the number of neurons:
$$ w_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^d q_{ik} \lambda_k q_{jk}$$
Hence the neural network has a $d$-dim vector $\lambda$ and each neuron $i$ has a $d$-dim vector $q_i$. The weights between neuron $i$ and $j$ are computed as described above. The vectors $q_i$ and $\lambda$ are learnt through gradient descent and backpropagation as is being done in Multilayer-Perceptrons. I have not a proof that this setting should allow the network to learn any function, but my vague idea goes like this:
If an ordinary MLP can learn any function, then it means it can learn any sort of symmetric weights $w_{ij}$. By allowing the 'Spectral Neural Network' to be able to express any sort of symmetric weights $w_{ij}$ through the spectral theorem, we could argue that the spectral neural network can adapt its parameters to learn any symmetric weights. But then it is an MLP which has learned  some specific weights for a given specific function $f$ and so it shoudl be possible to learn any function with the spectral neural network.
Modified question: Is it possible to make the idea of universal learning with spectral neural network more concrete, maybe a proof?
Comment: Of course for $d \ge n$ the savings in memory are lost, but I can imagine that there are situaitons of problems where $d << n$ and there we have not only savings in memory from $O(n^2)$ to $O(nd)$ but also a dimensionality reduction, kind of. The training process could start with $d=1$ and increase it fast or gradually specific to the problem.

Which value do you assign to diagonal elements ? Zero ?

@DenisSerre: I think $w_{ii} = |\mu_i|^2$ would be a good candidate but I am open for new suggestions, ideas.

in an $N\times N$ symmetric matrix the number of independent elements grows quadratically with $N$, while the number of variables in $\mu_i$ and $x_i$ only grows linearly with $N$, so I don't think what you want is possible in general; even if you impose translational and rotational invariance, the inverse square dependence on the separation is quite restrictive.

@CarloBeenakker The size $m$ of the vectors $\mu_j$ and $x_j$ might be larger than $N$. So there is no obvious obstruction. A similar problem is that of Euclidean distance matrices, where we ask $u_{ij}=|x_j-x_i|^2$ for some vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_N\in{\mathbb R}^m$. See Exercise 62 of my list http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/serre/DPF/exobis.pdf

A partial solution for the case in which the "mass vectors" $\mu_k$ are scalars. I am using the boldface font for vectors.
We can assume that none of the $\mu_k$ is zero, otherwise we would see rows and columns of zeros in $W$ that can easily be deflated. Hence all entries of $W$ are nonzero. Let $M$ be the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n)$. Then, clearly $W$ is a Coulomb matrix if and only if there exists $M$ such that $$E = M\operatorname{inv.}(W)M = (\|\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j\|^2)_{i,j=1,\dots,n}$$ is a Euclidean distance matrix (EDM); here with the operator $\operatorname{inv.}$ (with a dot) we denote the elementwise inverse of $W$, using Julia notation. We set the diagonal of $\operatorname{inv.}(W)$ to zero, by convention.
There are known characterizations of Euclidean distance matrices, as also @DenisSerre notes in a comment. In particular, a symmetric matrix $E$ with zero on the diagonal is an EDM if and only if it is negative semidefinite on the hyperplane $\mathbf{1}^\perp = \{\mathbf{v} \colon \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{v} = 0\}$ (here $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector of all ones). Clearly the matrix $E$ is positive semidefinite on $\mathbf{1}^\perp$ if and only if $\operatorname{inv.}(W)$ is positive semidefinite on
$$\mathbf{m}^\perp = \{\mathbf{v} \colon [\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n]^T\mathbf{v} = 0\}.$$ Since we can choose $\mathbf{m}$ arbitrarily, this is equivalent to asking that $\operatorname{inv.}(W)$ is positive semidefinite on a subspace of dimension $n-1$. Note also that the matrix $\operatorname{inv.}(W)$ always has at least one negative eigenvalue: it has zero diagonal elements and nonzero off-diagonal elements, so it is indefinite on the span on any two vectors of the canonical basis. Hence, we get the following criterion:
Let $(s_+, s_-, s_0)$ be the metric signature of the matrix $\operatorname{inv.}(W)$ (i.e., the number of its positive, negative and zero eigenvalues). Then, $W$ is a Coulomb matrix with scalar masses $\mu_k\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only $s_- = 1$.
In particular, quite surprisingly, it seems that the set of Coulomb matrices has non-empty interior.

Thanks for your partial answer. Do you think it can be extended to the case where $\mu$ is a vector, or what obstacles do you see?

@mat Unclear. In the best case, one would be able to prove that also Coulomb matrices with vector $\mu_k$ must satisfy the same property, so that every Coulomb matrix admits a representation in which $\mu_k$ is scalar. But I don't see a quick way to do it. One of the difficulties is that in the vector case $W$ can have isolated off-diagonal zero entries, when $\mu_i$ and $\mu_j$ happen to be orthogonal; so you cannot form $\operatorname{inv.}(W)$.

A similar family of matrices is that of Cauchy-like matrices, in which the denominator is a difference of scalars. And also in that case there are many more results for the case in which the "displacement rank" is 1, as opposed to being larger.

Thanks for the explanation.
